# Why can't my textures be found in Monogame/XNA?

Tags: c#, xna, filenotfoundexception, monogame, texture2d

I'm programming a Tower Defense game in XNA/Monogame and was doing just fine until i ran into this exception "FileNotFoundException" (I have it set to break when i get one of these and when  I continue it won't work). It says it can't find the new images ive added. i put them in the content folder and the rootdirectory is set to Content. The old images work but the new ones won't. Here's my Game1.cs (This is my first time programming a non text game so its a bit messy(The error is happening in the loadcontent function)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
//using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Net;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Storage;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Touch;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace KillTheBugs2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the main type for your game
    /// </summary>
    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        public Texture2D background;
        public GameTime gameTime;
        public Vector2 p;
        Level level = new Level();
        public Player player;
        public Ant ant1;

        SpriteBatch _spriteBatch;
        public GraphicsDeviceManager _graphics;


        public Game1()
        {

            _graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);

            _graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 2000;
            //This is wierd i will have to replace 32 with the size in pixels of 1 tile for some reason
            _graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 32 + 2500;
            _graphics.ApplyChanges();
            IsMouseVisible = true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
        /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
        /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
        /// and initialize them as well.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Initialize()
        {

            base.Initialize();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
        /// all of your content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            _spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
//background, ant, and blueberry bush wont load
            background = Content.Load<Texture2D>("background");

            Texture2D AntTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("ant");
            ant1 = new Ant(AntTexture, Vector2.Zero, 100, 10, 0.5f);
            Texture2D BlueberryBushTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("blueberrybush");
            player = new Player(level, BlueberryBushTexture);




            // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
        /// all content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
            // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
        /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            ant1.Update(gameTime);
            List<Bug> bugs = new List<Bug>();
            bugs.Add(ant1);

            player.Update(gameTime, bugs);

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {

            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);


            // TODO: Add your drawing code here
            _spriteBatch.Begin();
            level.Draw(_spriteBatch, ref background);
            ant1.Draw(_spriteBatch);
            player.Draw(_spriteBatch);
            _spriteBatch.End();

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are the new images also marked as Content in the properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark the new images added to the project as `Build Action` `Content` in the properties menu of the images, which is usually on the right side.

Comment: Where do i change it to Content?

Comment: Thank you for being quick to respond